# Confusion about elasticSearch timeout

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently using the ES 5.5 version
I have a questions about timeout

add timeout to the search request

```
GET s_all/_search
{
    "profile": true,
    "timeout": "1ms",
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "type": "sh"
        }
    }
}
```

Through the profile, know that it has exceeded the set time.

```
"profile": {
    "shards": [
    {
        "id": "[qVjmAo1oSXSptAEsqMT76g][s_all01][0]",
        "searches": [
        {
            "query": [
            {
                "type": "TermQuery",
                "description": "type:sh",
                "time": "14.28760800ms",
                "time_in_nanos": 14287608,
```

can be seen
**"time": "14.28760800ms",**  has exceeded one millisecond I set

but response timeout is:

```
"took": 57,  
"timed_out": false,
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue in the past as well, i ended up finding a somewhat satisfactory explanation. [source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3627).

> There is a node-level setting thread_pool.estimated_time_interval that dictates the resolution of the timer used to estimate current time for these sorts of checks (it avoids making timer checks too expensive in hot loops). The default resolution of this is 200ms.

Basically you can get skewed results by up to 2 clock rotations (400ms), I personally found this to be somewhat consisted (from my **minimal** testing).